# three js 3rd person camera not working

Tags: camera, three.js

I´m trying to implement a 3rd person camera on my object.

i´ve tried it with a cube and it worked fine

cube:

```
var object, camera;
cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 50, 50, 50 );
cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xFF0000 });
object = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, cubeMaterial );
scene.add( object );


camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, ASPECT, 0.2, 10000);
camera.position.z = -300;
camera.position.y = 100;
object.add(camera); 
camera.lookAt(object.position);
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

but with my model is doesnt work:

```
var object, camera;
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
loader.addEventListener('load', function (event){
    object = event.content;
    object.updateMatrix();
    object.scale.set(20,20,20);
    scene.add(object);
}, false);
loader.load( "models/dragster.obj", "models/dragster.mtl" );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, ASPECT, 0.2, 10000);
    object.add(camera);
camera.position.z = -300;
camera.position.y = 100;    
camera.lookAt(object.position);
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

when i add the camera to the scene it works, but when i add it to the object it doesnt

thanks in advance

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is not very descriptive.

Comment: in the firefox web-console a get an type-error: object is undefined

Comment: See if you can figure it out yourself, and if you have problems, then provide a live example and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple. The OBJ hasn't loaded by the time you're doing this:

```
object.add( camera );
```

Try moving that code to inside the eventlistener.